# SQL Server Express 2008 install parameters for command line

Tags: sql-server-2008, installshield

I'd like to install SQL Server Express 2008 with the InstallShield prerequisites.
I always get an error at the end of installation, but the installation works.
The error only says, that the installation fails.

Can anyone see the problem with my install parameters?
Here are my parameters for the installation:

```
SQLEXPR_2008_x86_DEU.exe 
/Q 
/ACTION=Install 
/SkipRules=VSShellInstalledRule RebootRequiredCheck 
/BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic 
/SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic 
/FEATURES=SQLEngine 
/INSTANCENAME=TCSERVER 
/SECURITYMODE="SQL" 
/SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\System"
/SAPWD="xyz" 
/SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS" 
/ENABLERANU=1 
/AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\System"
/TCPENABLED=1 
/ERRORREPORTING=1 
/HIDECONSOLE
```

I would be happy about help.

Markus

Comment: Have you looked into the [setup log files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702(v=sql.100).aspx)?

Comment: 2013-02-25 10:55:49.99 spid7s      Error: 15151, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2013-02-25 10:55:49.99 spid7s      Cannot find the object 'fulltext_stopwords', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: Did you Google the error message? It may be a [known issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976899) that's fixed in the latest service pack. So if you aren't using SP3, that would be the first thing to try.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your message. I try SP3, but there is the same error.